# Append items to [String: Any]() type array Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an dictionary like below:

```
var param = [String: Any]()
param = ["locale": "en",
         "token": "82ETaBYbiz2ZM2Kqg7eL8z3VL0",
         "taskId": 123]
```

Now I want to add some other values in same dictionary condition based like below:

```
if userType == "ADMIN" {
    param = ["userType": "ADMIN"]
} else {
    param = ["userType": "USER"]
}
```

But when I do like the same it replaces old value. So is there any way to perform this? Coz I have lots of conditions and lots of values to add to the dictionary. Please suggest the effective way to handle this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not using an array, you are using a [Dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary), which is a collection of key-value pairs. To add a new key and value, you would have to subscript the dictionary and add the new value. So your code should be like this:

```
if userType == "ADMIN" {
    param["userType"] = "ADMIN"
} else {
    param["userType"] = "USER"
}
```

Comment: Oh, my bad its dictionary. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is currently reassigning the whole dictionary to be a new one just containing a key `"userType"` and an associated value. If you just want to add that key to the pre-existing dictionary, you'd use a subscript:

```
param["userType"] = "ADMIN"
```